# Open Speak Dialog In Experience Editor Mode

Tags: experience-editor, speak

I would like to open a Speak dialog in Experience Editor mode. I have created a command and tied it to a button in core under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Page Editor`.

Here is my command:

```
namespace Common.Commands
{
    public class OpenDialog : Command
    {
        protected void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsPostBack) return;

            const string url = "/sitecore/client/Your Apps/MyModal?sc_lang=en";
            SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(url, "1024", "760", string.Empty, true);
            args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
    }
}
```

`SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog` is throwing an error when called in Experience Editor mode but does not when used in content editor mode.

Comment: Does this mean you answered your question below?  Just wondering.

Comment: @Marco it does but there might be an easier way to handle this/a way to do this from a normal command.

Comment: @Marco [Answering your own question is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but feel free to add different answers, there are usually multiple ways to do things in Sitecore.

Comment: @jammykam I get that.  I was wondering why he didn't accept it as answer.   With his answer on my initial comment, he's looking for an easier one as it looks like.

Comment: You can't accept your own answer for 2 days, just an FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something to go off of with the validation button in the Experience Editor's ribbon which also opens a modal. Copied that item that represented the validation button and edited some fields in the presentation details of the large button. I had to edit the command which had to point to my javascript command.

[image: Command field presentation details image]

I also needed to edit the PageCodeScriptFileName to point to my javascript file.

[image: PageCodeScriptFileName field presentation details image]

I made a request because I had some functionality I wanted to do server side (get the url of an item) but if I didn't have that requirement then the added request wouldn't have been necessary.

Button Item Renderings:

Speak js:

```
define(["sitecore", "/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js"], function (Sitecore, ExperienceEditor) {
    Sitecore.Commands.OpenModal =
    {
        execute: function (context) {
            ExperienceEditor.PipelinesUtil.generateRequestProcessor("Custom.OpenModal", function (response) {
                var dialogFeatures = "dialogMinWidth: 850px;";
                ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(response.responseValue.value, "", dialogFeatures, null);
            }).execute(ExperienceEditor.generatePageContext(context, ExperienceEditor.getPageEditingWindow().document));
        }
    };
});
```

Request:

```
namespace Common.CustomSitecore.Requests.SharedContent
{
    public class OpenModal : PipelineProcessorRequest<PageContext>
    {
        public OpenModal()
        {
        }

        public override PipelineProcessorResponseValue ProcessRequest()
        {
            var item = base.RequestContext.Item;

            var pipelineProcessorResponseValue = new PipelineProcessorResponseValue()
            {
                Value = new UrlString($"/sitecore/client/Your Apps/MyModal?sc_lang=en&itemUrl={item.GetUrl()}").ToString()
            };

            return pipelineProcessorResponseValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Request config:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
      <request name="Custom.OpenModal" type="Common.CustomSitecore.Requests.SharedContent.OpenModal, Common"/>
    </sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```